# setSelectionBackGround() doesn't set color in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I think that the `prepareRenderer(...)` is causing the trouble. My code for jTable creation is :-

```
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable(){
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    if(column==0){
        c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(223, 223, 223));
        c.setForeground(new Color(121, 63, 63));
        c.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12));
    }else{
        c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(235, 235, 235));
        c.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 12));

    }
    return c;
}
};
```

Now, when I use:-

```
    jTable1.setSelectionBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

it does not work. Any idea how to fix it?

**EDIT:**  I tested the program after completely removing the `prepareRenderer(...)` method and the black selection could me made

Comment: override isSelected/HasFocus, the same methods as for standard Renderer, but isn't required as parameter for prepareRenderer

Comment: @mKorbel, please read the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the solution...

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{
Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
if(column==0){
    c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(223, 223, 223));
    c.setForeground(new Color(121, 63, 63));
    c.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12));
}else{
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(235, 235, 235));//c.setBackground(..) was the problem
    c.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 12));

}
return c;
}
```

Comment: Component c is AWT parent, but whatever casted to JComponent e.g. JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;, aaach

Answer (score 1):

That's a code snippet from DefaultTableCellRenderer

```
    if (isSelected) {
        super.setForeground(fg == null ? table.getSelectionForeground()
                                       : fg);
        super.setBackground(bg == null ? table.getSelectionBackground()
                                       : bg);
    }
```

As you can see the selection background is set to the renderer (in fact in your call super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column))

After that you just reset the background to one of the colors depending on column. But no matter which is the column number you in fact replace the selection background.

if column!=0 call

```
c.setBackground(getSelectionBackground());
```